# open HTML from PowerShell with URL parameters

Tags: html, powershell, microsoft-edge

I am trying to open a HTML file in Microsoft Edge browser from PowerShell.

Below code opens HTML in Microsoft edge

```
&'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe' @('d:\test.html')
```

How to pass some values from PowerShell to HTML using URL parameters.
I wanted something like below code

```
&'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe' @('d:\test.html?testvalue1=45&testvalue2=50')
```

But the above code opens browser but cannot able to load test.html. Using JavaScript I want to get values from URL which is passed by PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the command below.

```
Start-Process microsoft-edge:"https://localhost?testvalue1=45&testvalue2=50"
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: above command worked as show in output but I need to open HTML file which is saved in local path

Comment: If possible, you could host that file on the IIS web server on that machine, then you will get the URL like above. It could help you achieve your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

One way to accomplish this is to use the "Start-Process" cmdlet

```
Start-Process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' C:\Web\index.html
```

This however only works if you know the path. For some reason Powershell fails to translate for example .\index.html to a proper path.